# I'm struggling with a task "Ask for the size of an array (in C)"

Tags: c

1. Ask for the size of an array;
2. Create a one-dimensional array;
3. Fill arrays with a random number between -6 and 6;
4. Calculate and display the average value of all numbers in an array;
5. Find and display the largest number from an array.

I'm new to C and can't solve the task. If it's possible can you guys help or give some hints

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int size=0; 
    int arr[size]; 
    printf("input size of array "); 
    scanf("%d",&size); 
    printf("\none - dimensional of array: "); 
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){ 
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]); 
    } 
    printf("\nThe array  is "); 
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){ 
        printf("%d",arr[i]); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You need to ask for the size before creating the array.

Comment: Put `scanf("%d",&size);` before `int arr[size];`. Statements are executed sequencially.

Comment: User input isn't random, nor is it restricted to the range -6..+6.

Comment: Check out `malloc` and `free` for assigning and clearing memory at runtime, plus look at random number generator `rand` and think about limiting results to `>= -6` and `<= 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int max = INT_MIN; //variable to get the maximum number in the array
    int avg = 0, sum = 0;
    int size=0; 

    //Ask for size of the Array before initializing
    //Use do-while loop to ensure that the number entered is valid
    printf("input size of array "); 
    do{
        scanf("%d", &size);
    }while(size < 0); 

    //Create the Array
    int arr[size];

    printf("\none - dimensional of array: "); 

    //Use rand(), to get a random number between 0 and INT_MAX
    //Then modulo the value of the random int by 13 to scale the value between [0, 12]
    //subtract by 6 to get a range of [-6,6]
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){ 
        int random = rand();
        random = random % 13;
        random = random - 6;
        arr[i] = random; 
    } 

    printf("\nThe array  is "); 
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){ 
        printf("%d",arr[i]); 
    } 

    //Get average of all elements, and the element with the maximum value
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){ 
        if(max < arr[i])
            max = arr[i];
        ums += arr[i]; 
    } 
    avg = sum/size;

    printf("\nAverage: %d", avg);
    printf("\nMaximum: %d", max);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should add a call to `srand`. And checking return value of `scanf` could be mentioned as well.

Comment: @Gerhardh if i set ```srand``` to a seed, it would still be a pseudo random number as the default seed of ```1```. side note: added a ```scanf``` loop to make ```size > 0``` a requirement.

Comment: It might not be a TRNG but using the same sequece every time you run the program is clearly worse than that.

Answer (score -1):

You should ask for the size before the array declaration

```c
int size=0; 
printf("input size of array "); 
scanf("%d",&size);
int arr[size];
```

For random you could use the `rand()` function from `stdlib.h` to generate the elements, but you need to scale to -6 and 6 because the rand only generates values in the inclusive range [0, `RAND_MAX`]. (`RAND_MAX` is `INT_MAX`)

Comment: @gspr where in the requirements did you find that?

Comment: @Gerhardh: I agree, it wasn't explicitly stated. Howver, there's also no stated bound on the size read into `size`. Most arrays of integers whose length fit into an `int` will surely blow the stack, no? At least with a `malloc`ed array, OP will be able to handle failures.

Comment: @gspr for this kind of beginner tasks the students normally don't need to take care about every detail of the solution. Finding a working way to solve the straight forward scenarios is sufficiently challenging.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Sure. But here there's absolutely no indication that the length will not be huge. OP will sure have a hard time debugging in that case, adding even more confusion. I suspect that recommending VLAs here will make OP's work *less* straightforward and *more* challenging.